# Application of a corollary of the Banach–Steinhaus theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I've already asked this same question earlier and I was given an answer involving a theorem we didn't really cover (teacher only gave us a corollary with no proof, we're supposed to see the proof of the more general theorem in a measure theory class later on this year.) so I figured I should use that corollary to solve the problem but I still struggle to get to my end.

Corollary : If a sequence of bounded operators $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ on a Hilbert space $H$ converges pointwise, that is, the limit of ${T_nx}$ exists for all $x$ in $H$, then these pointwise limits define a bounded operator $T$.

now I have to properly use that to show the following :

let $H$ be a Hilbert space

and $T : H \to H$ a linear operator such that $\forall x,y \in H \; \langle\,Tx,y\rangle=\langle\,x,Ty\rangle$

then $T$ is bounded

I have pretty weak skills when it comes to proving technical claim so sorry in advance if something doesn't make sense

since $H$ is closed there is for all $x \in H$ a convergent sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset H$ such that $x_n \to x$

and from the Cauchy Schwartz inequality we can affirm that the inner product is continuous in both its arguments

now : $\forall x,y \in H$

$$\begin{align}
\langle\,Tx,y\rangle=\langle\,x,Ty\rangle = \lim_n\langle\,x_n,Ty\rangle=\lim_n\langle\,Tx_n,y\rangle
\end{align}$$

assuming $\{ Tx_n\}$ converges to some $z$ then $z = Tx$

I'm stuck at this point

I don't know how I shall proceed to choose the sequence of bounded operators ?

any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks !

NOTE : I want to show the above using just that corollary.

Comment: Note that your attempt cannot really take you anywhere, as you could for instance take $x_n=x$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to use the Corollary.

Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis. You have 
$$\tag1
Tx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle Tx,e_n\rangle\,e_n=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m\langle x,Te_n\rangle\,e_n. 
$$
Let $T_m$ be the operator 
$$
T_mx=\sum_{n=1}^m\langle x,Te_n\rangle\,e_n.
$$
Then
$$
\|T_mx\|\leq\sum_{n=1}^m|\langle x,Te_n\rangle|\,\|e_n\|\leq\|x\|\,\sum_{n=1}^m\|Te_n\|.
$$
So each $T_m$ is bounded, and by $(1)$ we have $Tx=\lim_mT_mx$. By the Corollary, $T$ is bounded.

Comment: Why is $\sum_{n=1}^m||Te_n|| \leq M \in \mathbf{R}$? And what $M$ would that be?

Comment: There's no single  $M $ for all $m $, if that's what you mean. What I'm saying is that  $\|T_m\|\leq \sum_{n=1}^m\|Te_n\|$.